# Draw progress bar into button background

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to show a bar graph inside a Button, based on a input value of 0 to 100, eg. a value of 50 will fill the Bar to half the buttons height.

To achieve this I create a button at runtime.

```
            Button btn = new Button();
            _panel.Controls.Add(btn);

            btn.Size = new Size(btnW, btnH);
            btn.Location = loc;
            btn.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
            btn.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 2;
            btn.Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 12);
            btn.Text = "1";
            btn.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
            btn.Paint += btn_Paint;
```

Then in the paint event I do

```
        void btn_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {
            Button btn = sender as Button;
            Graphics g = e.Graphics;

            using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.PeachPuff)) {

                g.FillRectangle(brush, new Rectangle(0, btn.Height / 2, btn.Width, btn.Height/2));
            }
        }
```

However I'm getting this result

[image]

As can be since the filled rectangle overwrites the border and text, I see that there is no `PaintBackground` event on the Button.

Is there a way to fill a custom background of the button at runtime?

Comment: a) use ClientSize.Width etc! - b) use a semitransparent brush!

Comment: @TaW ```using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(128, 255, 218, 155))) {

    g.FillRectangle(brush, new Rectangle(btn.ClientRectangle.Left, btn.Height / 2, btn.ClientSize.Width, btn.Height/2));
   }``` tried this it words to some extent, but the fill color still overlaps the text and partially obscures it. Isn't there a way to access the background and draw graphics into it, so its drawn behind the text and other elements in the control.

Comment: No there isn't as far I know. You could set the text to "" and draw the string yourself. Anything you paint onto a control is always on top.

Comment: You will need to take over drawing of the entire control, if you want this to work. Note that that will include drawing not just the background and text, but also the border and focus rect. See marked duplicate for more information about the basic issue.